# How to get detail about 'OptimizationStatus.ERROR' in MIP module in Python?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, python

I am using MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) module in Python to solve one of my optimization problems. for some of the scenarios, model returns "ERROR" (OptimizationStatus.ERROR) status after optimization ends.

Is there a way to get more details about why am I getting this status? I tried catching an exceptions putting try/catch but there is no exception.

Comment: What solver are you using ? And what modeler ?

Comment: I am using CBC Solver and I don't know what do you mean when you say modeler? if this could help, I'm using this - from mip import Model

Comment: the python-mip documentation has a contact form at the top, i would ask this question to the developers. I did not found any way to retrieve this information.

Comment: @PyPyVk, have you tried another solver to check if the error would exist?

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the source code and OptimizationStatus.ERROR is returned if Cbc_isAbandoned evaluates to True. I can't see when this is the case but I would say that only occurs when something goes really wrong on a deeper system level.
Your best bet would be to ask the developers though as mentioned in a comment above.